# Java EE and outgoing TCP connections

Tags: jakarta-ee, networking, web-applications, tcp

So I'm facing a challenge to develop a web application which would have to display real time data coming from remote server. To connect to this remote location I'd need TCP sockets and some arbitrary protocol(not HTTP).

My goal is to have the web server connect to the other server, keep the connection alive indefinitely and continuously read data while displaying that data in real time on the website.

Now my question is, how would I go about this using Java EE? I could also develop completely separate software to handle the outgoing TCP connection, but how then would I handle communication between web app and this other software?

Comment: Whatever the solution, be careful to think about clustering from the start. By clustering, I am thinking about the fact that you might have to run more than one application server node behind a load balancer (for scalability and availability). Remember that (depending on your solution), you might have each app server node fetching data from the remote server. Think about what you need to do to ensure consistency of data presented in the web app.

Answer (score 1):

this is a rather broad question and there is several ways to do this.

one way is to have an mdb in the webapp that consumes from a queue that the external server is producing messages to. ive been doing this using glassfish and activemq messagebroker.

then primefaces push to send events from webapp to client browser

Answer (score 1):

The by-the-book way to solve this is creating an inbound resource adapter. Check out the [IronJacamar user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/userguide/1.0/en-US/html/introduction.html#overview_inbound) for an introduction on how to do this.